# VSTS agent utilization

Tags: azure-devops

Is there any way to find out **utilization** of build **agents** in **VSTS** (Visual Studio Team Services).

I have a feeling that agents are busy and builds are queuing for long time, so want to add one more agent. But to justify the cost to management I need to present some data, e.g. percentage of the time agent is busy doing builds, preferrably withing working hours.

Is there any such VSTS extension or tool to measure this and display?

See example how it's beautifully done in TeamCity:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Viewing+Agents+Workload

Answer (score 2):

There is no build agent utilization report or related API to generate it. I have submitted a UserVoice for this feature at website below, you can vote it:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17023195-add-a-report-of-build-agent-in-vsts-or-related-api

Including buying one or more hosted agents, you can also consider [deploying your own on-premises build agents](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/index#deploy_agent).

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that VSTS offers is to go to the **Settings** menu (the gear icon) and choose **Agent pools**.  Once the page loads, choose **Hosted** from the menu on the left (assuming you are using Hosted agents).  This will display each of your Hosted agents and their statuses, as well as a history of all requests, when they were queued, assigned, started, completed, duration, etc.

Comment: Chris, yes, I know about this view. I wonder if this statistics is available via API, so I can write a script to calculate % Usage

Comment: @Ivan I had checked the API too, but unfortunately only seems to return basic info about the agent.  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/queues/overview